# If »Geld« is neuter, then why not »genuges Geld«?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending

Usually one would say

> Hast du genug Geld?

But I was thinking, as *Geld* is neuter, then shouldn't one say

> Hast du genuges Geld?

Can some one please explain what is wrong with my thinking?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In this sentence the word »genug« (*enough*) does not describe a property of »Geld« (*money*). You can test this when you try to use this word as an attribute in a nominal phrase that is used as  subject in a sentences. This test works in German and also in English:

> Falsch: Das genug(e) Geld ist grün.
>   Wrong: The enough money is green.

This will not do. This is neither correct German nor correct English.

The word »genug« (*enough*) is a supplement of the verb, which in your example is a form of »haben« (*to have*). This kind of usage is called "adverbial". You can use the verb plus *genug/enough* together with a simple subject (here: a personal pronoun) to build an absolutely correct sentence in German and also in English:

> Richtig: Er hat genug.
>   Correct: He has enough.

In »*das genug(e) Geld*« we tried an *attributive usage*, but this lead to an error. In »*er hat genug*« we have an *adverbial usage*, and this times the sentence was correct.

Words that can be used adverbial but not attributive are called *adverbs*. Adverbs are different from adjectives. One of the most important differences is, that in German adjectives have to be declined according to their grammatical environment, while adverbs are indeclinable words. This means, that adverbs never will be declined. They never change the ending.

Since, as shown above, »genug« is not a adjective, but an adverb (exactly like its Englisch counterpart *enough*), it exists in only one form, which is »*genug*«. There is no »*genuge*« or »*genuges*« in German. It is always »*genug*«.

Comment: Thanks, it has been a long time since I used this approach to differentiate between adjectives and adverbs. This is a great tip.

Comment: This is mostly wrong. In these sentences ("Er hat genug Geld." or "Er hat genug."), "genug" is not used as an adverb, but as an indefinite pronoun. English also uses the term 'uncountable quantifier pronoun' for this subset of indefinite pronouns. See Duden for a more thorough explanation: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/genug_zureichend_hinlaenglich

Comment: I agree with @jarnbjo: the analysis here is wrong. The sentences in the first block are not incorrect because they appear in attributive position, but because they occur together with a determiner (*das*/*the*) which occupies the slot that they would normally go into. Try leaving out the articles – et voilà: *genug* in attributive position doesn't cause any problem at all. The sentences don't make much sense, true (unless you're forging money and care about the color), but they are grammatical nonetheless.

Comment: @Schmuddi: Muss es dann nicht "Das genügende Geld ist grün" (oder besseer: "ist im Umschlag") heißen?

Comment: @userunknown: No: *Genug Geld ist grün. Wir können mit dem Färben aufhören. Genug grüne Farbe wurde schon verbraucht.* Try to remember the many meanings that *genug* and *genügend" have.

Comment: @jarnbjo I agree with you, but I've nevertheless decided to upvote this, because the answer is still useful. And yet I think it would be great if you posted your own answer!

Comment: If it really was an attribute, shouldn't it be »Genuges Geld ist grün«?

Comment: @jarnbjo Grammar isn't some dead set of rules. There is much flexibility and fludity around. Some syntax analysis might classify it as a pronoun, but there is no one set of "correct" analysis and some others might disagree with this analysis, and ideas might well change after a few decades. Sure, Duden is considered to be relatively autoritative but this still doesn't mean it's the one true source of grammar. Directly calling out others as "wrong" is a bit judgmental I'd say.

Comment: It's not a mathematical formula type of thing. When people speak they don't consider formal grammar before speaking. Grammar is an attempt to classify and categorize the inherently chaotic and full-of-exception phenomenon of everyday speech, and is bound to have imperfections in doing so. It's not the other way round.

Answer (score 20):

*Genug* is an adverb in your example sentence. Adverbs in German do not take adjective endings.

Here's a similar example with the use of *genug* as an adverb from [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=genug&pagenum=2):

> Als ob ich nicht schon **genug** Probleme hätte. = As if I didn't have
>   **enough** problems.

The difference between adverbs and adjectives can be nicely (*nicely* here is an adverb, BTW) illustrated through the following three examples from dict.cc:

> schlecht bezahlte Arbeit {f} = badly paid job
>
> schlecht erzogener Hund {m} = badly behaved dog
>
> schlecht zugeschnittener Anzug {m} = badly cut suit

As you can see, *schlecht*, which is an adverb in the above expressions, does not have any endings. While adjectives that follow do have endings, as determined by the subsequent nouns.

Answer (score 13):

Addendum to the answers here,

the adjective form of the genug is **genügend**. It can be translated as **sufficient** in English.

Some examples from internet with this adjective;

> Ich war ohne Mittel, denn genügendes Geld bekam ich als Gefangener natürlich nicht in die Hände
>
> Sofort wenn wir genügendes Geld haben fahren wir hin

There was a [related question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7517/are-genug-and-gen%C3%BCgend-interchangable) whether *genug* and *genügend* can be used interchangeably. It is also useful to read it to understand the differences.

### EDIT

After the discussion about the examples, which I used. I am giving the sources of the examples.

The first example is taken from [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=qBOfJy1mhOMC&pg=PT126&lpg=PT126&dq=Ich+war+ohne+Mittel,+denn+gen%C3%BCgendes+Geld+bekam+ich+als+Gefangener+nat%C3%BCrlich+nicht+in+die+H%C3%A4nde&source=bl&ots=Jga80boPm3&sig=Ox0b1YJmywO6Oh0Y_4312NTAunI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw7IHFnIjTAhWGQBoKHW-0C6EQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Ich%20war%20ohne%20Mittel%2C%20denn%20gen%C3%BCgendes%20Geld%20bekam%20ich%20als%20Gefangener%20nat%C3%BCrlich%20nicht%20in%20die%20H%C3%A4nde&f=false).

The second example is taken from [Berlinische Galerie](http://sammlung-online.berlinischegalerie.de/eMuseumPlus?service=ExternalInterface&module=collection&objectId=194190&viewType=detailView).

However, with the help of the comments below, I understand that this kind of usage of the genügend is a little bit old-fashioned, even if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: All of your examples sound wrong to me.

Comment: I have taken them from books (google books). Sound they old-fashioned?

Comment: Hah, interesting. Do you still have some of the links?

Comment: The first one: https://goo.gl/i19lia  . But I have realized that the author is not native speaker. I will replace the examples with better ones.

Comment: I have replaced the examples. How do these new ones look like?

Comment: @AdInfinitum Still sounds off. "genügendes Geld" is a kind of money. "genug Geld" is an amount of money. Your examples work, but they still make me cringe.

Comment: In both sentences, I would accept "genügend Geld" and use "genug Geld" myself. "Genügendes" sounds wrong.

Comment: @AnoE These sample sentences are from the books. The first one is https://goo.gl/fvv8Gt and the second one is https://goo.gl/M1Vmbf

Comment: @AdInfinitum, the author of at least the first book died 1906, the author of the second book in 1931. Even German changed in the last 100 years. :-) As I said - I would accept "genügend" as not too unusual (if a little oldfashioned), but never use it in that context myself, and "genügendes" is more or less out of the question.

Comment: @AnoE I think also that this type of usage is old-fashioned. However, the OP is curious about why did not *genug* take ending and I would like to show the adjective version of the *genug* and with a link, which shows the usage of the *genügend*. Here, there is an interesting discussion whether genügend should take adjective ending or not :)

Comment: I think we can agree that they are grammatically correct. To me they sound off, but it may be that this used to be normal. I feel like it refers to some quality of the money that is sufficient, not the amount.

Comment: I have found a discussion about this topic. 

Somebody explain the difference so 

--Genügende Beispiele finden Sie...

**Das sind Beispiele, die genügen, ausreichen oder den Anforderungen entsprechen.**

Genügend Beispiele finden Sie...

**Das sind Beispiele, die genug sind, in der Zahl aureichend, für den Zweck hinreichend**  Source: http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,70917

Comment: I think the -es at the end of genügendes should not be there. Then it sounds valid.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thank you for editing! But *»here«* is not a useful caption for a link. The caption should give you a hint about what you can expect to find when you click on it. I corrected this for you. Next time please use meaningful captions.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/genug_zureichend_hinlaenglich) it is not an **adverb** but in this case a **pronoun**. (*Indefinitpronomen*).

Some are some are not inflected. This is not.

The adjective *'genügend'* would be treated as any adjective:

> *Es gab nicht genug Gründe.*

vs

> Es gibt keine *genügenden Gründe.*

Note that it can also be used as a **particle** [(*Partikel*)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/genug_sehr_recht_ausreichend):

> Der Schrank ist groß genug

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered satisfyingly well. I would just like to broaden the perspective on the more common (ab)use of adverbs in similar cases in informal oral language.

> Die Marmelade ist alle.

is a sentence you probably wouldn't find written anywhere, but you will hear quite often when sitting with a family at breakfast, "alle" meaning "finished" or "used to its end so that the jar is now empty". Now, it may happen that this gets turned into an adjective like in

> "Gib mir mal die Marmelade!" - "Welche?" - "Die allene, bitte."

This is clearly wrong in terms of grammar and style, but it is relatively common in informal language in some regions. People usually find it too circumstantial to form a grammar-conform sentence as in

> "Die, die alle ist, bitte."

Even more often you may hear:

> "Die Tür ist kaputt" - "Welche denn?" - "Die zuene da."

where "zuene" is an adjectivized form of the adverbial "zu" as correctly used in

> Die Tür ist zu.

and a well-formed but circumstantial sentence to answer the above question would be

> "Die, die zu ist."

"Zuene" came about in analogy to "offene", as in

> "Die offene Tür ist kaputt."

which is a completely well-formed sentence.

Comment: From your answer, can it be understood that **Hast du genuges Geld?** is used in informal language even if it is grammatically wrong?

Comment: *Die geschlossene Tür*, ja wohl. Und wenn unbedingt, dann doch "die zue Tür", wie "das raue Wetter". Apropos: "Die verbrauchte Marmelade" ("... hat gut geschmeckt." - reichen kann man sie ja nicht mehr).

Comment: Zuene?? Ecch. I can see that, when the only alternative is "geschlossene", one might be tempted to invent such a word, but pretty nasty nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

"Genug" does not modify "Geld."

Instead, it is an adverbial that works with "have. The sentence, ich habe genug geld really means:

I have enough **of** money.