# Genug/genügend/ausreichend Unterschiede?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Gibt es einen deutlichen Unterschied zwischen den Verwendungen von genug, genügend und ausreichend?

Zum Beispiel, gibt es zwischen den folgenden Sätzen Unterschiede?

> Das Kind kennt genug Wörter, um sich aus­drü­cken zu können.
>
> Das Kind kennt genügend Wörter, um sich aus­drü­cken zu können.
>
> Das Kind kennt ausreichend Wörter, um sich aus­drü­cken zu können.

Comment: Ist es ein Typo dass in den Zitaten steht "genügende" und "ausreichende"? Für die vermutete Satzintention wäre jeweils das letzte e zuviel.

Comment: _Genügend Wörter_ = "genügend viele Wörter"; _genügende Wörter_ = "unbestimmt viele Wörter, die alle genügen".

Comment: @ShegitBrahm und phipsgabler, Das war ein Fehler, danke für die Korrektur

Comment: Ich glaube [dieser](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7518/42065) post könnte weiterhelfen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German native speaker, here. To me, these sentences have the same meaning. If I would write them, I'd write "ausreichend viele" instead of just "ausreichend", but I guess that's just a matter of stylistic preference. "Genug" is slightly less formal than "genügend", but, again, this is not a different meaning, just a difference in style.